# Vue syntax rendered in HTML

Tags: javascript, vuejs2

I'm getting acquainted with Vue.js and reading and trying out someone else's code in order to understand what is going on.

While rendering HTML, i get Vue conditionals rendered on the page, like this [image: Screenshot of the page]

The HTML looks like this

`%div.validation-error v-if="errors.has('start')"
%p.error Bitte wählen Sie aus, ab wann Sie Ihren Austauschschüler aufnehmen wollen.`

What can be the reason for that? 
I have vee-validate added as script in the layout.

Comment: Inspect HTML itself. Maybe it's broken element that goes before?

Comment: That is not normal HTML and/or Vue.js template syntax. What template engine are you using?

Comment: it could be because you're using vue development version and not the production one (see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/#Getting-Started)

Comment: @str, i have the template written in HAML

Comment: @AnnaKizilova Then you should read their [documentation about attributes](http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes).

Comment: @str, thank you for your comment. The issue was really in broken HAML syntax, while specifying attributes.

Comment: If this question has been answered in the comments, can someone please remove it or answer it, to save others of us engaging with it needlessly. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [HAML](http://haml.info/) but are setting attributes values in a non-supported way.

See http://haml.info/docs/yardoc/file.REFERENCE.html#attributes for a reference:

> For example:
>
> ```
> %html{:xmlns => "http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml", "xml:lang" => "en", :lang => "en"}
> ```
>
> is compiled to:
>
> ```
> <html xmlns='http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml' xml:lang='en' lang='en'></html>
> ```